# Why is EF not persisting the new value?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, persistence, insert-update

**Question:** Why is this code not persisting the new Summary value to the database?  Let me know if I've omitted any surrounding/relevant code.

**Details:**

I have very little hands-on experience with EF, and I've just inherited a codebase that uses it extensively.  This extension method is in that codebase, with usage to follow:

```cs
public static void SafeAttachTo<T>(this ObjectContext context, string entitySetName, ref T entity) where T : IEntityWithKey {
            ObjectStateEntry entry; 
            bool attach;

            if (context.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(context.CreateEntityKey(entitySetName, entity), out entry)) {
                attach = entry.State == EntityState.Detached;
                entity = (T) entry.Entity;
            }
            else
                attach = true;

            if (attach) 
                context.AttachTo(entitySetName, entity);
        }
```

Usage:

```cs
    public int UpdateOrInsertWidget(Widget widget) {
        if (widget.Id == 0) {
            _context.Widgets.AddObject(widget);
        } else {
            _context.SafeAttachTo("Widgets", ref widget);
            _context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(widget, EntityState.Modified);
        }

        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

At some point, the user changes the Summary on a `Widget` (let's say the type has `Id` and `Summary` properties... we'll call this instance `changedWidget`), from "Old Summary" to "New Summary".

And so `UpdateOrInsertWidget` gets called like this:

```cs
UpdateOrInsertWidget(changedWidget);
```

After the call to `_context.SaveChanges();`, the database (SQL Server 2008) shows "Old Summary" in the Summary column.

The `entity = (T) entry.Entity;` line seems to be overwriting `changedWidget` when it's passed in, which seems bad.

But, w/o more EF experience, I'm struggling to figure out what about this code needs to change.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that your extension method is simply setting the `ObjectStateEntry` to be a state of "Modified", but the `ObjectStateEntry` does not know *what* has changed.

What you should be using instead is either `ApplyOriginalValues` or `ApplyCurrentValues`, these two methods apply the changes from a "detached" object to the object state entry in an existing `ObjectContext` and compare the changes so that the `ObjectContext` knows which specific properties have changed.

If you're attaching the *changed* entity to the context, then you need to `ApplyOriginalValues` so that the context can see what has changed from the original to what it has now.  Otherwise you need to use `ApplyCurrentValues`.

You can read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896248.aspx